# react native unbreakable text component

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to build unbreakable text component in react native ? I mean a text component whose content stays on one line and without ellipsis whatever the content is ? Indeed, I wrap it in a `ScrollView`.

I've tried the property `numberOfLine={1}`, but with that property I can't avoid ellipsis and truncation.

RN version is *0.43*

Android device is *4.2.2*

Comment: try `flexWrap: 'nowrap'` style rule

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've removed the numberOfLines prop on the component and set style to {
        height: 16,
        flexWrap: 'nowrap',
    } on its style, but it didn't worked. The text is still truncated when too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `maxHeight: <desired line height>,` and `maxWidth:<the width after which you want to truncate>` to keep the text to one line, truncated without ellipsis.

Comment: Thanks. I also would like the text component to take the screen width, including after screen rotations. I know I can use the Dimensions object, however, how to handle the screen orientation changes and adapt the width accordingly ?

Comment: Thank you @Cherniv for your comment, but it didn't work. I've tried `width: "100%"` and `maxWidth: "100%"` on the scrollview content style.